# nodejs, mongodb get array of only specified fields value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to get an array of a specified fields value in mongodb?

Like instead of getting:

```
[{"color":"blue"},{"color":"red"}]
```

I would like to get:

```
["blue","red"]
```

Is this question clear enough?

Comment: How would you know what properties' values to extract as the array contains objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `array.map` on the results array to achieve the desired result:

```
var colors = [{"color":"blue"},{"color":"red"}].map(function(obj){
    return obj.color;
});
```